# How to filter android logcat only for VPN

Tags: android, adb, vpn, logcat

I've got a general logcat successfully;But my particular problem is connecting to the VPN (on any 4+ android ROM) so I want to do a logcat related to VPN only and see what's going on.

Tried 'LegacyVpnRunner' in this way :

```
adb logcat LegacyVpnRunner:E *:S -v long > name of problem.txt
```

But the final txt was this:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
```

What's the problem? did I use a wrong alias for VPN service? (LegacyVpnRunner) if so, Where is the referernce to find related aliases for any android service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not limit your filter to capturing just `Error` priority messages. As for using proper tag
`com.android.server.connectivity.Vpn.java` uses 2 tags for logging - "Vpn" and "LegacyVpnRunner". So I would suggest trying both:

```
adb logcat -s Vpn:*
adb logcat -s LegacyVpnRunner:*
```